# Starts with number in xslt

Tags: xslt

Entries start with a number or the word "noon". Those will become  elements.

An end-nested-style character () should be placed at the end of the show's title, which is marked by a space followed by one of the following codes: MVLSC, 16VLSC, MSC, 16VL, ML, MC, PGC, 16VL

Input :

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td> 7.10    Between Worlds 16VLSC 2018 Thriller. Haunted by memories of his deceased family, a truck.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>A look at the latest movie trailers, coming soon to cinemas.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output :

```
<p type="Entry"><tab/>7.10<tab/>Between Worlds<char type="endNestedStyleHere"/> 16VLSC 2018 Thriller. Haunted by memories of his deceased family, a truck.</p>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="td[starts-with(.,'1234567890')]">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matches` in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="td[matches(., '^[0-9].*')]">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe you need to check for spaces too too if there could be whitespace before the number...

```
<xsl:template match="td[matches(., '^\s*[0-9].*')]">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, if you did want an XSLT 1.0 solution, you could do this...

```
<xsl:template match="td[contains('0123456789', substring(normalize-space(), 1, 1))]">
```